# Extract substring between given strings

Tags: string, kotlin

Given the following string: `be_de=Interessant für Dich; be_fr=Intéressant pour toi;`

What is the nicest way to extract the substring for a given locale in Kotlin? e.g. I have given the locale `be_fr` I want to have `Intéressant pour toi` as a result. The string is always in between the locale followed by a `=` and a `;`

There could be more locales with strings given, and the position of the value to extract always varies.

Of course I could just create a substring after the first index of my locale and then search for the fist index of the semicolon, but I assume there is a more elegant way like using `removeSurrounding`, which I can't think of atm.

Comment: Have you think using a different encoding like JSON or .properties file? It will be more suited for this kind of purposes.

Comment: See [this youtrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44095).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I don't think `removeSurrounding` applies here, as you can only remove text with that if you know exactly the entire `prefix` and `suffix` to remove.

I'd go with this, as it's very easy to read:

```
val result = data.substringAfter("be_fr=").substringBefore(';')
```

Comment: actually it could be `val result = data.substringAfter("be_fr=", "").substringBefore(";", "")` - empty strings means that if `delimiter` e.g. `be_fr=` is missing than the result will be an empty string. Otherwise you'll get origin string, which is astonishing behaviour for me.